# is there a way to get layout resource from ViewDataBinding instance?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I'am trying to build custom Recycler view adapter with data binding and i'am wondering if I can get the layout resource id from binding object instead of passing the layout resource every time
to the constructor

```
class BaseAdapter<dataType,binder:ViewDataBinding>(val data:ArrayList<dataType>,@LayoutRes val resource:Int,val onBind: (binder, dataType, Int) -> Unit]) {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseHolder {
    val v = DataBindingUtil.inflate<binder>(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
        resource,
        parent,
        false
    )
    return BaseHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseHolder, position: Int) {
    onBind(holder.binding, items[position], position)
}
```

}

on my activity I use it like this

```
BaseAdapter<String,MatchItemBinding>(arrayListOf(""),R.layout.match_item)
```

but instead I'am looking to do something like this :

```
BaseAdapter<String,MatchItemBinding>(arrayListOf(""), MatchItemBinding.SOMETHING_TO_GET_LAYOUT_LINKED_WITH_THIS_OBJECT)
```

Comment: do you need it for the ViewHolder? `binder.root` works there, e.g. `RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binder.root)`

Comment: I need it for onCreateViewHolder before initializing binder object
: like this

 DataBindingUtil.inflate<binder>(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            R.layout..............,
            parent,
            false
        )

Comment: can you include the code for your ViewHolder class? including onCreateViewHolder

Comment: done , question updated with holder code

Answer (score 1):

View.getSourceLayoutResId() was added in API 29 to provide this.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getSourceLayoutResId()

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work for you?

```kotlin
class BaseListAdapter<T, VDB : ViewDataBinding>(
    val data: ArrayList<T>,
    val onBind: (VDB, T, Int) -> Unit,
    val inflate: (layoutInflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup?, attachToParent: Boolean) -> VDB
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseListAdapter<T, VDB>.BaseHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseHolder =
        BaseHolder(inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))

    inner class BaseHolder(val binding: VDB) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
}
```

you can invoke inflate like this

```
{ li, parent, attachToParent -> SpecificDataBinding.inflate(li, parent, attachToParent) }
```

Comment: passing the layout resource is much simpler then doing this :) , i'am just wondering if there's a way of getting layout resource without passing more information , because i'am assuming that my ViewDataBinding object is related to only unique layout resource

Comment: fair - does `binding.root.id` work for you?